# Use amp component in amp-form success

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to use an amp-component in the amp-form validation success template?

I want to use another form (effectively step 2) in the success message

Comment: You could always make multiple forms and set visibility/submission bind to correct filling of first form.

Answer (score 0):

As @adnanyousafch stated, yes you could. Based from this [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components), the AMP HTML library provides components and [`amp-form`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form) is categorized in [Dynamic content](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components#dynamic-content). You may also check this [Learn AMP by Example](https://ampbyexample.com/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

While many amp-components can be wrapped/nested inside others, but there is a limitation on the traditional HTML form.

A HTML form must not contain another HTML form i.e. `[Nesting in forms is not allowed]`.

From [w3c HTML recommendations](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element),

> 4.10.3 The form element
>
> > Contexts in which this element can be used:
> >     Where flow content is expected.
> >
> > > Content model:
> > >       Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

Since in AMP-FORM, the `submit-success` and `submit-error` children element of the form element, adding another form inside it would not be rendered.

However, to produce a wizard-like form structure, you can toggle visibilities of multiple forms using the events on result of the form E.g. `on="submit-success:form1.hide,form2.show"` as described [Here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-form/amp-form.md#events)